# UITableView with complex cells is slow and laggy

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I've almost finished my app and everything seems to work but the main view.
It's an `UIViewController` with an embedded `UITableView`.
I'm using Parse as the backend, and I get an array of the objects I need in my `viewDidLoad` method.

Each cell contains some data that I'm fetching in the `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath` and I'm afraid that this is the reason why my table view is so laggy, but I don't know how to fetch the data I need for each object in my array without having the `indexPath.row` number.

I've already made each cell element "opaque" as suggested in other answers.

This is my code, any help would be greatly appreciated:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"cellHT";
    CellHT *cell = (CellHT *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[CellHT alloc]
                initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    // self.hH is an NSArray containing all the objects
    NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    cell.lblTitle.text = [self.hH[indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"title"];
    cell.lblVenueName.text = [self.hH[indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"venueName"];
    cell.lblDistance.text = NSLocalizedString(@"Distance from you", nil);
    self.geo = [self.hH[indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"coordinates"];

    // the formatters are initialized in the viewDidLoad: method
    self.formatData = [NSDateFormatter dateFormatFromTemplate:@"dd/MM" options:0 locale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];
    [self.formatterData setDateFormat:self.formatData];
    self.formatOra = [NSDateFormatter dateFormatFromTemplate:@"j:mm" options:0 locale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];
    [self.formatterOra setDateFormat:self.formatOra];
    self.dal = NSLocalizedString(@"from", nil);
    self.ore = NSLocalizedString(@"at", nil);
    CLLocation *vLoc = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:self.geo.latitude longitude:self.geo.longitude];
    CLLocation *user = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:self.userGeo.latitude longitude:self.userGeo.longitude];
    CLLocationDistance distance = [user distanceFromLocation:venueLoc];
    if ([[prefs objectForKey:@"unit"] isEqualToString:@"km"]) {
        cell.lblDist.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.1f Km", distance /1000];
    } else {
        cell.lblDist.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.1f Miles", distance /1609];
    }

    // compare the object's starting date with the current date to set some images in the cell
    NSComparisonResult startCompare = [[self.hH[indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"startDate"] compare: [NSDate date]];
    if (startCompare == NSOrderedDescending) {
        cell.quad.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"no_HT"];
        cell.lblStartTime.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
    } else {
        cell.quad.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"yes_HT"];
        cell.lblStartTime.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:104.0/255.0 green:166.0/255.0 blue:66.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
    }
    NSString *dataInizio = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@ %@ %@", self.dal, [self.formatterData stringFromDate:[self.hH[indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"startDate"]], self.ore, [self.formatterOra stringFromDate:[self.hH[indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"endDate"]]];
    cell.lblStartTime.text = dataInizio;
    PFObject *cat = [self.hH[indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"catParent"];
    NSString *languageCode = [[NSLocale preferredLanguages] objectAtIndex:0];
    if ([languageCode isEqualToString:@"it"]) {
        cell.lblCategory.text = [cat objectForKey:@"nome_it"];
    } else if ([languageCode isEqualToString:@"es"]) {
        cell.lblCategory.text = [cat objectForKey:@"nome_es"];
    } else {
        cell.lblCategory.text = [cat objectForKey:@"nome_en"];
    }

    //getting the image data from the Parse PFFile
    PFFile *theImage = [self.hH[indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"photo"];
    [theImage getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSData *data, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            cell.cellImageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
        }
    }];

    //getting the cell object's owner and his profile
    PFUser *usr = [self.hH[indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"parent"];
    PFQuery *prof = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Profile"];
    prof.cachePolicy = kPFCachePolicyCacheThenNetwork;
    [prof whereKey:@"parent" equalTo:usr];
    [prof getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock:^(PFObject *object, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            //getting the object's rating and the number of votes
            PFQuery *rateQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Rating"];
            [rateQuery whereKey:@"parent" equalTo:object];
            [rateQuery getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock:^(PFObject *object, NSError *error) {
                if (!error) {
                    float vote = [[object objectForKey:@"rate"] floatValue];
                    float temp = ((vote * 2) + 0.5);
                    int tempvote = (int)temp;
                    float roundedVote = (float)tempvote / 2;
                    // drawing the stars number, depending on the rating obtained
                    UIImage *starsImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"stars"];
                    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(cell.imgVoto.frame.size, NO, 0);
                    CGPoint starPoint = (CGPoint) {
                        .y = (cell.imgVoto.frame.size.height * (2 * roundedVote + 1)) - (starsImage.size.height)
                    };
                    [starsImage drawAtPoint:starPoint];
                    cell.imgVoto.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
                    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
                    cell.lblVoto.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"(%d)", [[object objectForKey:@"voters"] intValue]];
                }
            }];
        }
       }];
    return cell;
}
```

EDIT: this is the cell code:

```
+ (void)initialize {
    if (self != [HH class]) {
        return;
    }
}

-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
    if ( !(self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder]) ) return nil;

    self.cellImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"icona_foto"];
    self.cellImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleToFill;
    self.formatterData = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    self.formatData = [[NSString alloc] init];
    self.formatterOra = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    self.formatOra = [[NSString alloc] init];
    self.formatData = [NSDateFormatter dateFormatFromTemplate:@"dd/MM" options:0 locale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];
    [self.formatterData setDateFormat:self.formatData];
    self.formatOra = [NSDateFormatter dateFormatFromTemplate:@"j:mm" options:0 locale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];
    [self.formatterOra setDateFormat:self.formatOra];
    self.lblVoto.text = @"(0)";

    return self;
}
```

SECOND EDIT: this is the code in the `viewDidLoad` method:

```
        PFQuery *hours = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"HH"];
        hours.cachePolicy = kPFCachePolicyCacheThenNetwork;
        // here I'm making lots of query constraints that I'll not include

        [hours findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
            if (!error) {
                self.objectsNumber = objects.count;
                self.hH = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:objects];
            }
        }];
        [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code for `CellHT`?

Comment: I've edited the question to include the cell code.

Comment: Have you profiled the table in Instruments? The Time Profiler instrument will tell you exactly where the time is being spent.

Comment: Please forgive me, but i don't know how to use the Time Profiler. I've began programming in Objective-C few months ago. I'll try anyway.

Comment: I tried the Time Profiler. While scrolling the table view, I see the 52.8% of running time is for Main Thread and 30.5% for _pthread_start. No idea what that means.

Comment: Another big source of lag in situations like this is from scaling the images when they are assigned to the image view.  When you get the images in the first place, create a "thumbnail" version that is the EXACT SIZE needed in the cell and it should speed things up a lot.

Comment: Re: Time Profiler, you need to drill down beyond the top level until you find something of interest. Try expanding the main thread row by clicking the arrow in the Symbol Name column. Also open the right panel (click third icon in the View section on the toolbar) to see the heaviest stack trace.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would move as much of the logic out of `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` as you can, it needs to be very light-weight to get good scrolling performance.  You're doing a lot of work on the main thread, and I would do a lot more of this work when you get your model objects back from Parse (if you could post `viewDidLoad` I can give you more specific help) and update the table view when these calls are done:

- `[UIImage imageWithData:data]`
- anything to do with `NSDateFormatter`
- `CLLocation`'s `initWithLatitude:longitude:`
- creating the rating stars image

None of these depend on the state of the table view, so they can be effectively precomputed and cached in a model object.  If you simply scroll up and down the table, you're doing allo f the same work over and over, killing your performance.

---

Updated for the questioner's newest code:

I won't include all of your functionality here but this should give you an idea:

```
// create a single shared formatter instead of one per object
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [NSDateFormatter dateFormatFromTemplate:@"dd/MM" options:0 locale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];
NSDateFormatter *timeFormatter = [NSDateFormatter dateFormatFromTemplate:@"j:mm" options:0 locale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];

[hours findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
    if (!error) {
        self.objectsNumber = objects.count;

        for (SomeObject *modelObj in objects) {
             // if you can add properties to your model object directly, do that
             // otherwise write a category on the Parse object to add the ones you need
             modelObj.dateString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@ %@ %@", modelObj.dal, [self.dateFormatter stringFromDate:[modelObj objectForKey:@"startDate"]], modelObj.ore, [self.timeFormatter stringFromDate:[modelObj objectForKey:@"endDate"]]];

             // create your locations, images, etc in here too
        }

        self.hH = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:objects];
    }
}];]
```

Then in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`, take the precomputed properties and simply assign them to the appropriate labels, image views, etc.

It would be even better to do most of this processing off the main thread via GCD, but that is most likely out of scope for this question.  See [Using GCD and Blocks Effectively](http://nachbaur.com/blog/using-gcd-and-blocks-effectively) for more information.  Just remember do only interact with UIKit from the main thread!

Comment: @Aleph72 added some code to give you an idea of how to move things to `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: I'll try it immediately. About the GCD, the `findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock`automatically uses background threads and dispatches the main thread if needed.

Comment: It was my understanding that the Parse fetch was in the background but then it calls your own block on the main thread.  If that's not true, then you can disregard my GCD comment.

Comment: I'll ask that in the Parse forum, since I really don't know it.

Answer (score 1):

have a try by removing

```
CLLocation *vLoc = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:self.geo.latitude longitude:self.geo.longitude];

CLLocation *user = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:self.userGeo.latitude long  itude:self.userGeo.longitude];

CLLocationDistance distance = [user distanceFromLocation:venueLoc];
```

This was at first sight , then I see your all your code and I realize a lot of image are used

Comment: Removing those lines reduces the lag a lot! But I need to calculate the user's distance from a point contained in each object, how could I do it before loading the cells?

Comment: you have to calculate it ahead and store in an array

Comment: You mean a new array only for that data?

Comment: Or do this in the background like you do some of the other code.

Answer (score 0):

Because `UITableView` takes some time to layout cells.

**Solution:**

step1. Set section number and row number to `0`.

step2. Reload tableView in `viewDidAppear`.

Then your view controller cloud response quickly and then show cells.